# What are the odds of a mob in minecraft dropping all 4 peices of armor that it is wearing?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing Minecraft Bedrock with a sharpness 2 and unbreaking sword (so no looting) and killed a drowned wearing full gold armor, killed it, and it dropped all 4 pieces of armor and almost full durability. Can somebody tell me the odds of this happening?

Answer (score 1):

There's a 5% chance that any armor will drop, and the only way to change that is to create a custom mob. Also, looting doesn't affect chances of a mob's armor dropping. Mob armor never drops with full durability, most likely it will be broken before it is dropped. And, rare drops occur 2.5% of the time. There are 6 possible rare drops from a zombie, 4 of which are armour, which I will assume have the same chance of happening. Therefore the percentage of zombies that will drop a piece of armour is 1.67%, or a chance of 0.0167.

Comment: I should probably add that in the context of armored zombies, there was a point in time where you could drown them in a body of water, and since drowns can't wear armor or hold the types of weapons that regular zombies can, the items would pop of the drown, so were guaranteed to drop whatever they were holding or wearing in their true durability (rather than the rng durability loss drop mechanic effecting the item's durability), being the most reliable way to get full durability armor and weapons from zombies. I'm not sure if this is still a feature anymore, but it's quite easy to test out.